# Difficult in understanding question of minimum stopping distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A car moving with a speed of 40 km / h can be stopped by applying brakes after at least 2 m. If the same car is moving with a speed of 80 km / h, what is the minimum stopping distance.

As I have interpreted the meaning of this question  is as that a car moving with a speed of 40km/hr can be stopped or reach the rest position , Only when brakes are applied after 2m of distance covered by the car.

The formula for minimum stopping distance is $\frac{u^2}{2a}$ . From this formula , I need to retardation that will be caused in the 1st case and then equate it with the 2nd case. I am not getting how to find it from the 1st case only since it is not given how much distance will it travel after brakes are applied.

Comment: It is given 2m u have mentioned

Comment: @Anusha But it applies brakes after 2m distance is travelled by car.It didn’t apply brake and then travelled 2m.

Comment: I suppose you have to regard the deceleration as the same in both cases ($=u^2/2x$, follows from the third kinematic eq) and then use the third kinematic equation to find how far it will travel before $v=0$.

Comment: @AdrianHoward If the question is badly worded.How are others understanding.Why am I not getting it that way ?

Comment: @user284851 It is badly worded. But stopping 2 meters after the brakes are applied is the only way it makes sense

Comment: That is the form perspective of concept . Only if you know what is stopping distance , you can say “ ok, maybe it meant stopping distance “ but if it is given to someone who doesn’t know that concept.He can’t even imagine it because it wrongly worded.Similarly, the one who knows the concept can’t also imagine it but doing it so , since he knows the concept.@AdrianHoward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying the question is not completely clear to me, however I tried my best to make a sensible interpretation of it.

> A car moving with a speed of 40 km / h can be stopped by applying brakes after at least 2 m.

This means that if having a speed 40km/h at a point in time, and the breaks are kicked into the maximum, then it takes 2 meters to completely reduce the velocity of the car to zero. From this, we can figure out the maximum retardation we can produce from the breaks.

> The formula for minimum stopping distance is $ \frac{u^2}{2a}$ . From this formula , I need to retardation that will be caused in the 1st case and then equate it with the 2nd case. I am not getting how to find it from the 1st case only since it is not given how much distance will it travel after brakes are applied.

I'd say this is a problem of the formula you are using, instead consider the following 'more general' formula(*):

$$ v^2 -u^2 = 2as$$

Where v is the final velocity, u is the initial, a is the 'constant acceleration' , s is the distance.  For your particular case, we want the car to become at a halt in both cases, substitute $ v=0$ , then:

$$ -u^2 = 2as$$

Plug the numbers in from the first case to figure out $a$ , now for the second case plug the newly found out acceleration with the velocity into the same equation to isolate for distance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting it after breaks are applied the car doesnt stop instantly , there is some regarding distance travelled by car which is given as 2m

---

You see retardation is the rate with which velocity decreases which means after the brakes were applied the car started regarding and took some time . In this time the car travelled some distance which is 2m